# Is the Call of Duty Elite service available for PC?

Tags: call-of-duty-elite

I currently have a pretty decent group of members and we want to create a clan and make a name for ourselves. All of this to get more familiar with the average gamer and so to expand our member base. I have been searching online but can't seem to find any information regarding CoD Elite actually existing for PC.

Can anyone confirm whether or not CoD Elite is available for PC?

Answer (score 2):

Call of Duty ELITE is not available for PC as far as I can see.

This was taken from the [Call of Duty ELITE FAQ](http://www.callofduty.com/elite/faq) page:

> We are currently evaluating options for Call of Duty® Elite to support the PC and Nintendo’s Wii U™ game system, however Call of Duty® Elite for Call of Duty®: Black Ops 2 will not support these two platforms when the game launches on November 13th.

Answer (score 1):

The Call of Duty Elite mobile application is only available for mobile devices, however all this does is act as a mobile client-side front end to the Call of Duty Clan HQ with some minor integration with Call of Duty: Black Ops II or Call of Duty: Modern Warfare® 3 in the forms of load out editors and the ability to view your player statistics.

Comment: I do not play any Call of Duty games so I'm unable to sign up and register, but [this might be what you're after in terms of an online alternative](https://elite.callofduty.com/?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Felite.callofduty.com%2Fplayer%2Fhome)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The link you provides goes to the website of COD-Elite but as i understand it, that site doesn't support PC. Please correct me if im wrong.